# Is there a vector that can handle integers of nonstandard bit-lengths?

Tags: c++, boost, stl

I'm looking for something resembling an STL vector but can handle integers that are, for example, 12, 16, 20, 24, 32, and 40 bits long. The 16-bit and 32-bit cases are handled wonderfully by `vector<uint16_t>` and `vector<uint32_t>`, but I haven't been able to find any way to handle the other ones. Note that the whole purpose of going this way is to save memory and bandwidth, so padding is not an option.

My data structure can infer the most significant bits of the integers (which are int64s), hence I only want to store the LSBs. The bits-per-integer and number of integers are known at creation time, but not compile time. Ideally bits per integer can be any value between 12 and 40, but tiers are ok for performance reasons or to work with a structure where bits-per-integer needs to be set at compile time.

`vector<bool>` and [dynamic_bitset](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html) can create bitfields, but they're limited to 1-bit integers. Anyone know of something else out there?

Comment: You'll need to do your own shifting and masking for that.

Comment: @Henning, I've got a prototype system going that does just that, but I'm trying to avoid re-inventing the wheel. I've also noticed that getting good performance is a tricky thing here, so something that has already been tuned would be very welcome.

Comment: Since you indicated that the goal here is to conserve memory and performance, I've removed my original answer (as it was more suited to esoteric reasons of why this would be necessary), but I still think that a `vector<uint64_t>` is likely the best solution.  Then you don't even need to infer any data, just store the entire value.

Comment: @Chad, if I can use a 20-bit integer instead of a 64-bit one then that means I can fit a problem that's 3 times bigger. That's a HUGE benefit.

Comment: If your problem only needed 20-bit integers, yes.  But it needs up to 40-bit integers.  Unless you can break the problem down into smaller pieces (meaning only 20 bit integers in one problem set, vs only 32 bit integers in another) you're not likely to find a one size fits all solution.

Comment: Does vector<uint8_t> for example take up for every element 4 bytes (padding, i.e. a vector<uint8_t> uses same amount of space like vector<uint32_t>)? Or does it do similar compression like vector<bool>, so that vector<uint8_t> only takes up quarter of space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is none in the STL.

I understand you performance concern, and notably the memory issue. However unaligned reads (requiring bit-shifting) can be slower than regular ones (on bytes boundaries), so I would suggest keeping to whole bytes. This means:

- 12 bits, 16 bits: `uint16_t`
- 20 bits, 24 bits: either 3 `uint8_t` or 1 `uint32_t` (tradeoff speed/memory)
- 32 bits: `uint32_t`
- 40 bits: either 5 `uint8_t`, 3 `uint16_t` or 1 `uint64_t`

Assuming you choose the easier solution (ie, always bumping to the next available integer), you could use something like:

```
boost::variant<
  std::vector<uint16_t>,
  std::vector<uint32_t>,
  std::vector<uint64_t>
>
```

This let you choose the exact `vector` to be used at runtime, based on the number of bytes you need to store.

If you want to spare as much as possible, then you simply need to add a `std::vector<uint8_t>` to the list. But I would refrain from doing so and perhaps only "pack" the 40 bits case (in `uint16_t`) as the others never waste much memory anyway... and I would probably profile to check both alternatives.

*Note: you might also wish to tune the vector memory usage by checking that the `capacity` does not exceed the `size` too much.*